# How to Insert Parametric Unicode Value in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have to insert Russian characters in a column.

It can be done with:

```
insert into tbl_test(name)
values(N'ŞİĞİL')
```

That is right but I have to do in SP something as `@pName` is a parameter.

So,

```
insert into tbl_test(name)
values(N@pName)
```

Is not a right syntax.

Is there any way with code or have an option in options?

Thanks.

Comment: Is type of the 'name' column nvarchar(...) also?

Comment: yes it is but seeing '????'

Comment: where do you see '????'

Comment: pal i know how to use mssql exactly. of course i see with a select query in name column.

Comment: Is your table column also a nvarchar type ? From what programming language are you calling your Stored Procedure ?

Comment: try to insert 'Араб' text with parameter. not with values(N'Араб') with values(@param)

Comment: MaxiWheat: It is not important which language is. I have a Russian text in my text column, those writings of the top is just an example.
When i split it and insert to columns which is name, surname, etc.
Query inserts it unidentified characters like "????" The problem is i don't know to do that with '@param'. Because i will do it with N'asdasd' manually. But it is transaction and i have not few records, I have 100000 records. So i have to do it with @param method.

Comment: I mean it is happening in MSSQL, not .Net, Java or C++

Comment: Also: **HOW** are you **CALLING** your stored procedure? How and what do you supply as value for the stored procedure call??

Comment: It is not the what i am saying. It is not important, what it is important is this query without SP or sth doesn't insert right characters. Try with declaring parameter please, ok?

Comment: Please post your complete code including that calling the stored procedure. Using an `nvarchar` parameter and inserting to an `nvarchar` column definitely works fine. If this isn't working for you there must be something else you are doing.

Comment: How you're calling the stored proc **CAN** have an impact on the outcome. Are you running this script from SQL Server Management Studio or from a programming language ? And you did not yet answered the type of the column involved.

Comment: I can't post it, my reputation is low, waiting time...

Answer (score 3):

Using nvarchar (unicode string) for your parameter type should do the trick:

```
create procedure dbo.spAddName
@name nvarchar(100)
as

insert into tbl_test(name) values(@name)

GO
```

**UPDATE**

Apparently the problem seems to be in your calling code, not in the definition of the stored procedure which is what others were trying to help with.

Here is a full example of how one might call the above stored procedure correctly, both from t-sql and from c#.

```
-- create a test table
create table dbo.tbl_test (
name nvarchar(100) NOT NULL
)
go

-- prove that a simple insert succeeds
insert into dbo.tbl_test (name) values (N'ŞİĞİL')

-- simple select against the unicode column to return the characters verbatim
select name from dbo.tbl_test

-- execute the original stored procedure from t-sql
dbo.spAddName N'ŞİĞİL'
```

...and now with c# and ado.net, just to provide an example invocation from application code.

```
const string cnStr = @"Server=.;Database=test;Trusted_Connection=Yes;";
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(cnStr)) {
    cn.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.spAddName", cn)) {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100) {
                Value = "ŞİĞİL"
            });
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    cn.Close();
}
```

In the future you're more likely to receive more help if you're more courteous to those attempting to assist.

Good luck!

Comment: @ErçinAkyüz: if **both** your *parameter* as well as the *column* in the table are in fact `nvarchar` - then there should be no issue at all with russian (cyrillic) characters.

Comment: Create Your DB and...

<i>
use TEST
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test1]
(
 [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
 [Ad] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [Soyad] [nvarchar](50) NULL
)

</i>

Try to insert...

<i>
use TEST
declare @Name nvarchar(50)
set @Name='Араб'

INSERT INTO dbo.Test1  (Ad)
VALUES (@Name ) 

select* from dbo.Test1
</i>

And look at table values!

Please dont answer, if you hasn't tried that query before.

Comment: @ErçinAkyüz `SET @Name='Араб'` is the problem. It should be `SET @Name=N'Араб'`

Comment: Pal, look at my question please, and read it carefully. I know it can be done with SET @Name=N'Араб', but i need to set text with SET @Name=@parameter because i am using a transaction in a stored procedure.

Comment: @ErçinAkyüz - I don't like your attitude to people trying to help you "pal". If you expect help you need to provide the code that isn't working as clearly you have made some sort of mistake in it similar to the above. I won't be providing you with any help though.

Comment: Tahbaza: Thank you for interested in subject. But you didnt understand again. Let me explain from your code:
-- execute the original stored procedure from t-sql
dbo.spAddName N'ŞİĞİL'

That is your code, but i don't want this because i am selecting much more than one data, i am selecting in a transaction or while or if statement etc. So, I want to execute it with not this way: 'dbo.spAddName N'ŞİĞİL', i want to execute This way: dbo.spAddName @pName.

Comment: Because @pName is always changing it is has not constant value, it's changing with when i received new SMS. It comes from another SP, not comes from DotNet. And, i am not asking code from you here, i am asking a way if you guys know it. You are expecting me polite but even you write in code; constant value, but i want parametric value. The problem is that, i try to explain it in my question. I am not newbie, it is my first post in this forum. I search that subject in everywhere in this forum also. There are questions about parametric value, but answers contains constant value :(

Comment: I can't share whole project it's too long. So, i give you example for that. I am using SMPP protocol in windows services. Incmng Msg data is Russian too, that data seeing normal but when i split data which are Password,Name, Surname etc. named to other columns; insert statement has that problem. Thanks...

Comment: @Erçin Akyüz: `@name` is a parameter. `ŞİĞİL` is only a test value; replace with a variable from your own code.  Provide more clarity on your situation in your question if everyone, including myself, is still misunderstanding you.

Comment: Tahbaza: Yes, it is test value. Look at my question please, i don't know how to replace that to insert statement. I want to insert with this statement but @pName must be inserted as unicode. How can i do that?
insert into tbl_test(name)
values(@pName)

Comment: unfortunetely, declaration as nvarchar is not enough. try with russian text, you will understand me :) all unicodes doesnt response same. Some of them is inserted truely, some data isnt. Should i identify Russian Collation?

Comment: for ex: i can't identify the parameter value as @Name=N'Араб'; i can identify @Name='Араб', because it is data mining and N@Name is not appropiate for syntax, N''+@Name+N'' parametric part still not unicode etc...

Comment: because set statement is like that:
Set @Name=@CurrentWord

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
This solution worked for me: http://www.dbafire.com/2015/06/21/convert-varchar-column-to-nvarchar-techniques-and-best-practices/

Answer (score -1):

I realized the problem, collation must be changed for parametric values. Try that lines, step to step.

```
ALTER DATABASE TEST SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE

ALTER DATABASE TEST COLLATE Cyrillic_General_100_CI_AS

ALTER DATABASE TEST SET MULTI_USER
```

But, if there are dependencies in DB,

```
ALTER DATABASE TEST COLLATE Cyrillic_General_100_CI_AS
```

is not working. You must remove dependencies and then try it.

Thanks.

Comment: -1 This is not the case. Collation only makes any difference to characters supported for `varchar`/`char` parameters not  `nvarchar`/`nchar`

Comment: In my case yes it makes difference.I didn't declare any varchar or char, I always declare nvarchar for strings. And you still trying to not understand inffectiveness of N'text' :)

Comment: I can assure you that if you are using `nvarchar` for all parameters and variables and the `N` prefix for all string literals you **do not** need to change the collation.